# watermark files on the fly when served

Tags: amazon-web-services, mp3, watermark, epub

I am looking for a very general answer to the feasibility of the idea, not a specific implementation.

If you want to serve small variations of the same media file to different people (say, an ePub or music file), is it possible to serve most of the file to everybody but individualized small portions of the file to each recipient for watermarking using something like Amazon WS.

If yes, would it be possible to create a dropbox-like file hosting service with these individualized media files where all users “see” most of the same physical stored file but with tiny parts of the file served individually? If, say, 1000 users had the same 10 MB mp3 file with different watermarks on a server that would amount to 10 GB. But if the same 1000 users were served the same file except for a tiny 10 kB individual watermarked portion it would only amount to 20 MB in total.

Answer (score 1):

An EPUB is a single file and must be served/downloaded as such, not in pieces. Why don't you implement simple server-side logic to customize the necessary components, build the EPUB from the common assets and the customized ones, and then let users download that?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, of course, yes, it can be done, using an EC2 instance -- or any other machine that can run a web server, for that matter.  The problem is that any given type of media file has different levels of complexity when it comes to customizing the file... from the simplest, where the file contains a string of bytes at a known position that can simply be overwritten with your watermark data, to a more complex format that would have to be fully or partially disassembled and repackaged every time a download is requested.

The bottom line is that for any format I can think of, the server would spent some amount of CPU resources -- possibly a significant amount -- crunching the data and preparing/reassembling the file for download.  The ultimate solution would be very format-specific, and, as a side note, has really nothing to do with anything AWS other than the fact that you can host web servers in EC2.